# Copy over data from previous rows in oracle 11g table

Tags: oracle

Our DB is Oracle 11g. I have a table with the structure is as shown below:

```
Person_Id |  Eff_Dt    |   Wid | Prv_Wid
----------------------------------

P1       |   1/1/2001   | 2001 |    
P1       |   1/10/2001  | 2001 |  
P1       |   10/10/2001 | 2002 |  
P1       |   1/1/2002   | 2003 |  
P1       |   5/4/2002   | 2003 |     
P1       |   8/6/2002   | 2002 |  
P1       |   1/1/2005   | 2001 |  
P1       |   1/10/2006  | 2001 |
```

I have a requirement that the Prv_Wid should be derived from the previous row's WID. But if the current and previous WIDs are same, then I have to go to the old previous row where the WID is different and put it in my current row's Prv_Wid.
It should be as shown below:

```
Person_Id | Eff_Dt | Wid| Prv_Wid
----------------------------

P1        | 1/1/2001    |    2001   |    0  
P1        | 1/10/2001   |    2001   |    0  
P1        | 10/10/2001  |    2002   |  2001  
P1        |  1/1/2002   |    2003   |  2002  
P1        |  5/4/2002   |    2003   |  2002  
P1        |  8/6/2002   |    2002   |  2003  
P1        |  1/1/2005   |    2001   |  2002  
P1        | 1/10/2006   |    2001   |  2002
```

I have tried several ways like lead, lag, first_value, last_value and procedure to achieve. But, I am not successful. Could you please provide any solution?

Comment: Show us the solutions you tried.

Answer (score 1):

All right, so we need some mechanism to keep track of the previous wid value regardless of the number of repeating values, so we can not use `LAG` directly, because we do not know how far back was the last different value.

Our data is:

```
with data as
(
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2001-01-01' as eff_dt, 2001 as wid from dual union all
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2001-01-10' as eff_dt, 2001 as wid from dual union all
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2001-10-10' as eff_dt, 2002 as wid from dual union all
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2002-01-01' as eff_dt, 2003 as wid from dual union all
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2002-05-04' as eff_dt, 2003 as wid from dual union all
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2002-08-06' as eff_dt, 2002 as wid from dual union all
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2005-01-01' as eff_dt, 2001 as wid from dual union all
  select 'P1' as person_id, date'2006-01-10' as eff_dt, 2001 as wid from dual
)
select
 *
from
 data
order by
 eff_dt
;

PE EFF_DT            WID
-- ---------- ----------
P1 2001-01-01       2001
P1 2001-01-10       2001
P1 2001-10-10       2002
P1 2002-01-01       2003
P1 2002-05-04       2003
P1 2002-08-06       2002
P1 2005-01-01       2001
P1 2006-01-10       2001
```

I will not repeat the `with` section any more to save space. Let's calculate a new field, called `prev_marker` as:

If `wid = previous wid`, this field becomes `NULL`. If `wid != previous wid`, this field gets the value of the previous `wid`

```
select
  person_id,
  eff_dt,
  wid,
  case when lag(wid) over (order by eff_dt) != wid
    then lag(wid) over (order by eff_dt)
    else null
  end as prev_marker
from
  data
order by
  eff_dt
;

PE EFF_DT            WID PREV_MARKER
-- ---------- ---------- -----------
P1 2001-01-01       2001 (null)
P1 2001-01-10       2001 (null)
P1 2001-10-10       2002        2001
P1 2002-01-01       2003        2002
P1 2002-05-04       2003 (null)
P1 2002-08-06       2002        2003
P1 2005-01-01       2001        2002
P1 2006-01-10       2001 (null)
```

Using this coluumn, we can get the desired `prv_wid` value with the `LAST_VALUE` function if we inspect rows up to the current row. The trick is, that the `LAST_VALUE` function supports the `IGNORE NULLS` option, so when we encounter a `NULL` value, we can easily ignore all the rows with the same `wid` and fall back to the previous value:

```
select
  person_id,
  eff_dt,
  wid,
  last_value(prev_marker ignore nulls) over (order by eff_dt rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as prv_wid
from
(
select
  person_id,
  eff_dt,
  wid,
  case when lag(wid) over (order by eff_dt) != wid
    then lag(wid) over (order by eff_dt)
    else null
  end as prev_marker
from
  data
)
order by
  eff_dt
;

PE EFF_DT            WID    PRV_WID
-- ---------- ---------- ----------
P1 2001-01-01       2001 (null)
P1 2001-01-10       2001 (null)
P1 2001-10-10       2002       2001
P1 2002-01-01       2003       2002
P1 2002-05-04       2003       2002
P1 2002-08-06       2002       2003
P1 2005-01-01       2001       2002
P1 2006-01-10       2001       2002
```

Our last task is to replace the `NULL`s with `0`s, that is just a simple `NVL`:

```
select
  person_id,
  eff_dt,
  wid,
  nvl(last_value(prev_marker ignore nulls) over (order by eff_dt rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 0) as prv_wid
from
(
select
  person_id,
  eff_dt,
  wid,
  case when lag(wid) over (order by eff_dt) != wid
    then lag(wid) over (order by eff_dt)
    else null
  end as prev_marker
from
  data
)
order by
  eff_dt
;


PE EFF_DT            WID    PRV_WID
-- ---------- ---------- ----------
P1 2001-01-01       2001          0
P1 2001-01-10       2001          0
P1 2001-10-10       2002       2001
P1 2002-01-01       2003       2002
P1 2002-05-04       2003       2002
P1 2002-08-06       2002       2003
P1 2005-01-01       2001       2002
P1 2006-01-10       2001       2002
```